# How do you scroll to a specific div in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe

I have a div with an iframe in it like so:

```
<div>
    <iframe ng-src="{{somesourceurl}}"></iframe>
</div>
```

The the source that gets loaded by the iframe has html with uniquely identified div tags like this:

```
<div id="n_1">
    <div id="n_2" />
    <div id="n_3" />
    <div id="n_4">
        <div id="n_5" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I also have a bunch of buttons that corresponds to each of these uniquely tagged divs like so:

```
<button onclick="goToN1()">Go To n1</button>
<button onclick="goToN2()">Go To n2</button>
<button onclick="goToN3()">Go To n3</button>
<button onclick="goToN4()">Go To n4</button>
<button onclick="goToN5()">Go To n5</button>
```

What do I put in my onclick functions for each of these buttons such that they will scroll to the appropriate place in the iframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can change the `src` of the `iframe` to make the browser scroll to the element with `id`:

HTML 1

```
<div>
    <iframe id="my-iframe" ng-src="{{somesourceurl}}"></iframe>
</div>
```

HTML 2

```
<button onclick="goToId('n_1')">Go To n1</button>
<button onclick="goToId('n_2')">Go To n2</button>
<button onclick="goToId('n_3')">Go To n3</button>
<button onclick="goToId('n_4')">Go To n4</button>
<button onclick="goToId('n_5')">Go To n5</button>
```

JavaScript

```
function goToId(id) {
    var iframe = document.getElementById("my-iframe");
    var src = iframe.src;
    if(src.indexOf('#') >= 0) src = src.substr(0, src.indexOf("#"));
    iframe.src = src + "#" + id;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest changing `onclick` by `ng-click` in your code.

Comment: @Mistalis Why??